# Get Apache to serve Markdown as HTML

Tags: apache-httpd, html, markdown

Like many people, I prefer writing in Markdown - is there a `mod_markdown` or similar that will let Apache serve Markdown content but render as HTML ?

Comment: @marolu - while an interesting alternative, that doesn't really answer the question :)

Comment: The way I see it is that browsers do not read Markdown, it is translated by the server into `<b>`s and what not. I am sure there are scripts out to covert MD to ML in whatever language (Turing-complete) you are wanting to use

Comment: You can use pandoc or Jekyll to build markdown pages as HTML.

Answer (score 8):

This sort of syntax is typical for a wiki engine, but they mostly propose similar syntaxes other than Markdown.  However, 
you can try [MDwiki](http://dynalon.github.io/mdwiki/#!index.md):

> MDwiki is a CMS/Wiki completely built in HTML5/Javascript and runs 100% on the client. No special software installation or server side processing is required. Just upload the mdwiki.html shipped with MDwiki into the same directory as your markdown files and you are good to go!

It really is that simple. Follow the [tutorial](http://dynalon.github.io/mdwiki/#!quickstart.md). This is a renderer, not an in-page editor.

Comment: I use this and it is pretty amazing.  However it is a dead project for the past five years now.  No longer supported.

Comment: @AlanObject - do you know of any currently-maintained similar project?

Comment: @warren Nope.  I ended up writing my own Angular application to do what I wanted.

Comment: @AlanObject - don't suppose you've made it available anywhere?

Comment: @AlanObject maybe it's "feature complete"? Sure, sure, keep jQuery up-to-date on your end and all that, but maybe it's just… [finished](https://josem.co/the-beauty-of-finished-software/).

Answer (score 6):

Yes, there is https://github.com/hamano/apache-mod-markdown.

There is a package for arch linux but there seems to be no debian package. However, the instructions in the README are written for Debian/Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any such Apache module, and I'm not sure that it would even make sense to have one.

However, Markdown is implemented in many different languages (including `php`, `perl`, `python`, `java` etc), and many blog/wiki/CMS etc programs written in those languages have either built-in or plugin-provided support for Markdown.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown#Implementations

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not a good idea, since markdown is used to create HTML fragments not full pages. Those fragments would then be inserted into a document with a head and body. You could use Apache's server-side includes to insert markdown-created fragments into your site's standard page structure. To do that, install the markdown renderer from Gruber's [site](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/) and call it from an [SSI tag](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/ssi.html).